# Google maps event when all markers are placed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm making a map for a website, where I have a Google map that needs to have around 30000 markers put on it. The time it takes to plot all the markers is not an issue, but I have a "loading" icon that needs to disappear when all the markers have been placed. Right now it disappears when the map has loaded and it starts to place the markers. I have tried adding listeners for all the events Google list on [their own events API example page](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html), and none of them fire when all markers have been loaded. I thought maybe `idle` would have fired, but it fires when the map has been shown, and not when markers are put on, which is a good 5-10 seconds after showing the map.

I use MarkerClusterers, and I have also tried binding the `clusteringend` event, but that happens at the same time of idle, for some reason.

Is there an event that fires when all markers are loaded, or can I fake one?

Comment: Do you use [MarkerClustererPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html) as it has `clusteringend` event?

Comment: I do, yes. It has some improved functionality over the standard MarkerClusterer that I needed.

Comment: You say that you added `clusteringend` event listener and it even doesn't work? There must be a problem with your adding function because as far as I see in the plugin, `google.maps.event.trigger(this, "clusteringend", this);` is the end of adding cluster. You probably looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711736/fire-event-after-markerclusterer-has-finished , I share just in case.

Comment: I think you are looking at the right event. Show us your code.